# How to retrieve the whole page screenshot be awesomium?

Tags: .net, awesomium

The problem is that width and height are set during WebView creation and I don't see any option to change it after page was loaded (and real size became known). To workaround it I use two WebView: first to get the size and second to make a screenshot:

```
static bool finishedLoading;
static bool finishedScroll;
static ScrollData scrollData;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   WebCore.Initialize(new WebCoreConfig() { CustomCSS = "::-webkit-scrollbar { visibility: hidden; }" });

   var webView1 = WebCore.CreateWebView(800, 600, false);
   webView1.LoadURL("http://someurl");
   webView1.LoadCompleted += OnFinishLoading;

   while (!finishedLoading)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(100);
      WebCore.Update();
   }

   webView1.RequestScrollData();
   webView1.ScrollDataReceived += new ScrollDataReceivedEventHandler(ScrollDataReceived);

   while (!finishedScroll)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(100);
      WebCore.Update();
   }

   var webView2 = WebCore.CreateWebView(scrollData.ContentWidth, scrollData.ContentHeight, false);

   finishedLoading = false;
   webView2.LoadURL("http://someUrl");
   webView2.LoadCompleted += OnFinishLoading;

   while (!finishedLoading)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(100);
      WebCore.Update();
   }

   webView2.Render().SaveToPNG("filePath");

   WebCore.Shutdown();
}

static void ScrollDataReceived(object sender, ScrollDataEventArgs e)
{
   finishedScroll = true;
   scrollData = e.ScrollData;
}

static void OnFinishLoading(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   finishedLoading = true;
}
```

I hope there is a better way...

Comment: can you help me out? the new version does not have the render and loadurl method anymore. how can i get the screenshot in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new WebView after you receive the scroll dimensions, you just need to resize it using WebView.Resize and then wait for the resize operation to complete (see WebView.IsResizing).

I recently wrote a tutorial on how to capture whole web-pages using Awesomium: http://labs.awesomium.com/capturing-web-pages-with-c/

The code uses the C API but it should be very similar to the .NET API. There's also a complete code example (link is near the bottom) that demonstrates how to capture very long web-pages to multiple images without killing your RAM.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, it was very useful! I have missed Resize method as Resharper doesn't show it when you type "size" :(

Comment: Hi @Adam, currently I am evaluating WebKit (either using wrapper such as Qt or Gtk) to try to convert a webpage into PDF. I see http://wkhtmltopdf.org that proves to be rather good in producing PDF (although, sometime it seems unable to properly render the PDF). Now I see your Awesomium and in the process of testing the screenshot feature as mentioned in your answer. So, do awesomium has PDF conversion ability built-in, or it's something that we must implement ourselves? Thanks!